# Google Docs Script: Sharing a script in my account / unreviewed scripts via Marketplace (replacement for previous chrome add-ons store)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

Am I correct that there is NO direct replacement for this process on marketplace:

- publish unlisted on chrome add-on store
- directly share the link with others who can use the script

In particular, the mechanisms allowed me to use a script that I write across all my google dsocs.

With the move to marketplace, is there any way in which I can do this? I.e., write a script (container-bound or otherwise) and have access to it from ALL my google docs?

This is not about privacy: I am super-happy for the script to be shared with others or be public, but the review process has already turned down the script as unfinished. However, the script does what I need it to do... so I'd like to be able to use it across my google drive primarily... however, with the new google marketplace that doesn't seem to be possible.

One way may be via Google Suite domains. That seems to allow for internal publication. However, I've done that, and so far not received an acknowledgement or notification (while the GSuite page says 'under review'). My understanding was that internal scripts weren't subject to review.

Would anybody be able to comment on this and confirm, clarify or refute this understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move to Marketplace has certainly caused a lot of confusion! Trying to find all the tick-boxes can be difficult.

The two main places to look are the OAuth Consent Screen, where you need to make sure it is Internal (you have to have a GSuite account for that):

[image]

And the Marketplace SDK under Configuration check it is set to Private (although note that if it has transferred from the Chrome store it may already be set to Public, and this can't be changed). And under Publish it is set to unlisted.

This "unlisted" setting may be the crucial one for you as even if it is "Public" it won't be in the Marketplace, but will only be available via a link. But if it is "Public" I don't think you can make updates without going through the verification process. But if you don't go through the verification it should still be available.

Hope this helps, happy to answer any other questions.

Andrew

Comment: Thank you for the answer - that's great. Here's another knotty question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469944/driveapp-in-library-with-script-running-on-domain